# R Squared missing from output of coxph

Tags: cox-regression

I'm new to R and am doing an online course. I'm running a cox model, but not getting an r squared value in the output. Anyone know why?

```
cox2 <- coxph(Surv(fu_time,death) ~ age_cat)
> summary(cox2)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(fu_time, death) ~ age_cat)

  n= 1000, number of events= 492 

                   coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
age_catUnder 65 -1.4264    0.2402   0.2402 -5.938 2.88e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

                exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
age_catUnder 65    0.2402      4.164      0.15    0.3846

Concordance= 0.549  (se = 0.007 )
Likelihood ratio test= 56.34  on 1 df,   p=6e-14
Wald test            = 35.26  on 1 df,   p=3e-09
Score (logrank) test = 41.66  on 1 df,   p=1e-10
```

Answer (score 0):

R packages are "live", they change with time. Form version 2.44 of the package "survival", summary.coxph does not report R2 anymore.
You can read the reason for this in the "Changes in version 2.44":

> The Nagelkirke R^2 has been removed from summary.coxph. The
>   shortcomings of this measure are well known, concordance is a better
>   measure.